# MongoDB update the path would create conflict at path error

Tags: mongodb

In production, just updating the path "z" in MongoDB collection would create a conflict at path "z".

I am trying to stimulate the same error locally.

I have a collection like this.

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.test.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("64050396a27f4d08e8c3a0d4"), "a" : 10, "b" : 4444 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("640504d3781e448660488d79"), "a" : 1000, "b" : 4444, "d" : 4444 }
```

I am trying to update it. According to Mongo tests, running an update query would cause conflicts. But when I try from Mongo shell it succeeds. I am not sure what am I missing.

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.test.update({"a":1000},{$set:{"a":100}, $set:{"a":900}, $set:{"a":10000}});
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 }
```

Test code reference from MongoDB source code is here. According to Mongo tests it fails. What am I missing?

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/bfebe1d457d4a1bbe2a0b9a1e8421215d016ee54/src/mongo/db/update/update_object_node_test.cpp#L1334

Comment: Please provide the error message for more information

Comment: @tbhaxor Here is what it looks like:   D3 WRITE    [conn13387910] Caught Assertion in update: ConflictingUpdateOperators: Updating the path 'lastRequestTime' would create a conflict at 'lastRequestTime'

Comment: update operation is attempting to set the "a" field to three different values

Comment: Your local test is running into a JavaScript limitation. Only one of those "$set" fields are being sent to the server

Comment: Here's [a mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UYOBUBysHjz) of generating the error.

Answer (score 0):

the error came from the `$set` with repetition key

> If the name of the new field is the same as an existing field name (including _id), $set overwrites the existing value of that field with the value of the specified expression.
> reff:  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-set

so, you are only able to change the value, not the existing field key.
and, you cannot `update` the same key in one query $set.

> The
> $set
> operator replaces the value of a field with the specified value.
> reff: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update

to successfully your requirment, you will need to use `aggregation pipeline` with the update operation

note: support starting from v4.2 => [update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)

the code would be like:

```js
db.test.update({
  "a": 1000
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "a.v": 2
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "a": 2
    }
  }
])
```

[MONGO PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_xPSmlkdifG)